# Django template if else condition problem

Tags: django

I am building a friend request system for my project. For this , i have implemented the below where one user can send a request to another.

1. If users are not friends(relationship does not exist in friends object), then ADD FRIEND option is visible.
2. If users are friends , then being logged in as "from_user" , the "to_user" profile page now shows REQUEST SENT.

My query comes after this, when i log in from "to_user" account and open "from_user" profile , the button should be ACCEPT ! Cant figure out the if else for that ! In my set up it shows ADD FRIEND. Hence need help to do this.

Models.py

```
class Friend(models.Model):
from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
related_name="added" )
```

Views.py

```
class ProfilePage(DetailView):
model = models.UserCreation
context_object_name = 'profile'
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProfilePage, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    user = User.objects.get(username=UserCreation.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk')))
    print(user)
    print(self.request.user)
    try:
        context['data'] = ProfileData.objects.get( user=user)
        context['userdata'] = User.objects.get( username=user)
        context['creationdata'] = UserCreation.objects.get( user=user)
        context['sorted'] = sorted(chain(AddStatus.objects.filter(user=user), ImageLib.objects.filter(user=user)),key=lambda instance: instance.date, reverse=True)
        context['friend'] = Friend.objects.get(from_user=self.request.user , to_user = user)

    except ProfileData.DoesNotExist:
        context['data']= None
    except Friend.DoesNotExist:
        context['friend']= None
    return context
```

Template

```
{% if user.get_username|stringformat:'s' != creationdata.user|stringformat:'s'  and creationdata.user|stringformat:'s' != friend.to_user|stringformat:'s' %}
    <a href="{% url 'usercreation:addfriend' data.user.usercreation.pk %}"  class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right">Add friend</a>
{% elif user.get_username|stringformat:'s' == friend.from_user|stringformat:'s' %}
    <a href="#"  class="btn btn-primary disabled" style="float:right">Request sent</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Your template doesn't even have the 'Accept' button in it; I'd say you have to provide full context/details if you're looking to get a decent answer.

Comment: @Alex i know thats missing, but thats the help i need, to incorporate the same. I have tried several combinations and methods but every time it fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if friend %}
  {% if friend.from_user_id == user.id %}
    <a href="#"  class="btn btn-primary disabled" style="float:right">Request sent</a>
  {% endif %}
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'usercreation:addfriend' data.user.usercreation.pk %}"  class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right">Add friend</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Did you try it? Was it helpful?